# NodeJS - String to array set

Tags: node.js

I have a string set of -

```
"uid:ID1,name:Name1,uid:ID2,name:Name2"
```

I want to map "uid:ID1,name:Name1" into

The following format

```
{
uid :'ID1',
name: "Name1"
}
```

But for it to make as many property sets as are passed in via the string set.

So for the input string with "2 sets" I need it to make this following output.

```
        {
            uid :'ID1',
            name: "Name1"
        },
        {
            uid :'ID2',
            name: "Name2"
        }
```

What can I try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `main` function below:

```js
const main = str => {
  // split on each comma
  const arr = str.split(',');
  // put back elements by pairs
  const pairs = [];
  for (let i=0; i<arr.length; i+=2) {
    let o = {};
    o.uid = arr[i].split(':')[1];
    o.name = arr[i+1].split(':')[1];
    pairs.push(o);
  }
  return pairs;
}

console.log(main('uid:ID1,name:Name1'));
console.log(main('uid:ID1,name:Name1,uid:ID2,name:Name2'));
```

This assumes that the input string is well-formed as a repetition of `uid:...,name:...` (no arbitrary key, no optional key) joined by `,`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want Objects and the keys are arbitrary...

```js
console.log(
  "uid:ID1,name:Name1,uid:ID2,name:Name2"
  .split(/[,:]/)
  .reduce((res, val, i, arr) => {
    if (i % 4 === 0) {
      res.push({})
    }
    if (i % 2) {
      res[res.length - 1][arr[i - 1]] = arr[i]
    }
    return res
  }, [])
);
```